# When Super is called in Flutter Bloc?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I have the following code of a Bloc:

```dart
class BetBloc extends Bloc<BetEvent, BetState>{
  BetBloc() : super(BetInitial() ){
    on<LoadBet>(
        (event, emit) async {
          return;
}

        }
    );
```

and in main.dart and other sub-screens I use `MultiBlocProvider` in the build method

```dart
return MultiBlocProvider(
          providers: [
            BlocProvider(
              create: (context) =>
              BetBloc()..add(LoadBet()),
            )
          ],
          child: ...
```

I can't understand when and why `super(BetInitial() )` sets the state to BetInitial. Because every time I change screen the state is reset to BetInitial, even if I don't throw an Event.
Hope I explained well enough

Answer (score 0):

In bloc super() is used to define the initial state of an app. This means what will be the state of an app when you will not call any event or not emit any state. For more info about the bloc go through the bloc documentation.
https://bloclibrary.dev/#/